# Synchronizing on a object and changing one of its field

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I am trying to understand a part of code which involves synchronizing on an object and one of the synchronized blocks changes some fields of the object. The code I am looking at is similar to the following:

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB someObject = new ClassB();

    public void FuncA() {
        synchronized(someObject) {
            //change some field of someObject
        }
    }

    public void FuncB() {
        synchronized(someObject) {
            //change some field of someObject
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a safe practice to do? I have read a few pages online describing the safe practices for the locks but none seem to deal with a similar example.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is also a [similar tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) in the Java documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

For example, this is basically what you (can) do when writing to an `ArrayList` from multiple threads: you synchronized on the list, and update its fields (the internal array, size etc).

The caveat is that you mustn't also access the `someObject` in a non-synchronized way anywhere.

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB someObject = new ClassB();

    public void FuncA() {
        synchronized(someObject) {
            //change some field of someObject
        }
    }

    // ...

    // BAD! Don't do this.
    public void FuncC() {
        // read some field of someObject
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to synchronize the access to a method.
One appears better than another according to the synchronization requirement.

> Is this a safe practice to do?

It is a safe practice if it is used for a use case that suits.
Here the synchronization makes sense as it locks on `someObject` which the two methods perform modifications on them.
Yes you could synchronize on `this` or synchronize the whole methods such as :

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB someObject = new ClassB();

    public void FuncA() {
        synchronized(this) {
            //change some field of someObject
        }
    }

    public void FuncB() {
        synchronized(this) {
            //change some field of someObject
        }
    }
}
```

but these would lock the whole object while this may not be required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is safe. `someObject` is private so only `FuncA` and `FuncB` have access to it. They both synchronize on `someObject` so only 1 of the methods at a time will execute on `someObject` even if from different running threads.

Note that it is important that all methods of `ClassA` that want to access `someObject` should do so within `synchronized` on `someObject` to avoid any risk of reading or writing inconsistent state into `someObject` (unless you understand exactly what you are doing!).